# Android Navigation bar appearing when in full screen

Tags: android

In my application, I have set it up in the XML so it is in full screen using

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Now this works fine when the app opens, however if while using the app, I use the home button to back out of the app, and then open it again, when it opens, a black navigation bar will appear for a second or two before disappearing. This does not occur if I exit the app using the back button, just the home button.

Does anyone know why this happens? I have tried doing it from code instead using

```
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Remove notification bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

However, what this does is removes the title bar, but the black bar is there at the top, just nothing is in it.

I.e. this bar

[image]

I tried combining the code, by putting the full screen line of code in the XML and also adding the code I showed above into the app, but same thing happens. If I back out of the app with home button and enter it again, that black bar will appear for two seconds temporarily pushing the app and its contents down before righting itself again.

How do I go about fixing this? I have been trying loads of different solutions, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to a bug with Android OS. Only way to fix it is go to device, settings animation, and disable animations.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove animation by setting->brightness->animation 
set no animation there